# How center items in recyclerview when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

How center items in recyclerview when user scrolling,in this case in mode horizontal and show same items in the recyclerview and center items in scroll, how next examples:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
new LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```